# how to calculate the power of a signal in MATALB?

Tags: matlab, math, wireless

I have a plot of my received signal, I do not have the equation of the signal. The signal is in time domain. also I have it in frequency domain by using fft()
how can I calculate the power of this signal?

Comment: How is power defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/measure-the-power-of-a-signal.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power of a signal is the squared of this rms value. You can use: *rms(signal)^2* where signal is your signal and rms() is a Matlab function

Comment: what is my "signal" ? I only have a plot of the signal. it means I have some amplitude values based on time. the x-axis is time, and the y-axis is amplitude. what is the input to the rms() function?

Comment: You "signal" is the array that you plot, I think you have that array.